# R shiny text scroll of sidebar panel

Tags: r, shiny

I have following side bar panel in R shiny dashboard

```
dashboardSidebar(
tags$style(".fa-ship {color:#5DADE2}"),
tags$style(".fa-shopping-cart {color:#5DADE2}"),
tags$style(".fa-dollar {color:#5DADE2}"),
tags$style(".fa-keyboard-o {color:#5DADE2}"),
tags$style(".fa-line-chart {color:#5DADE2}"),

sidebarMenu(
  menuItem("Vessel Line-Up Coal Quantity", tabName = "coal_quantity",
           icon = icon("ship", lib="font-awesome")),

  menuItem("Coal Stocks at Port", tabName = "coal_stocks",
           icon = icon("fa fa-shopping-cart", lib="font-awesome")),

  menuItem("Coal Price", tabName = "coal_quan_price",
           icon = icon("dollar", lib="font-awesome")),

  menuItem("Forecasting Weeks", tabName = "man_input",
           icon = icon("keyboard-o", lib="font-awesome"),
           numericInput("forecast_days", "Week ahead forecast:",5, min = 1, max = 500)
  ),

  menuItem("Coal Price Forecasting", tabName = "coal_forecasting",
           icon = icon("line-chart", class = "fa-spin",lib="font-awesome"))

)
),
```

I want to add text scrolling effect for `Coal Price forecasting` text in sidebar. 
How can I add it?

Comment: What do you mean by text scrolling?

Comment: From left to right

Comment: Like we get it from `<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="right">Your slide-in text goes here</marquee>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Text Scrolling"),
    dashboardSidebar(
      tags$style(".fa-ship {color:#5DADE2}"),
      tags$style(".fa-shopping-cart {color:#5DADE2}"),
      tags$style(".fa-dollar {color:#5DADE2}"),
      tags$style(".fa-keyboard-o {color:#5DADE2}"),
      tags$style(".fa-line-chart {color:#5DADE2}"),

      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("Vessel Line-Up Coal Quantity", tabName = "coal_quantity",
                 icon = icon("ship", lib="font-awesome")),

        menuItem("Coal Stocks at Port", tabName = "coal_stocks",
                 icon = icon("fa fa-shopping-cart", lib="font-awesome")),

        menuItem("Coal Price", tabName = "coal_quan_price",
                 icon = icon("dollar", lib="font-awesome")),

        menuItem("Forecasting Weeks", tabName = "man_input",
                 icon = icon("keyboard-o", lib="font-awesome"),
                 numericInput("forecast_days", "Week ahead forecast:",5, min = 1, max = 500)
        ),
        menuItem(
          HTML('<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left">Coal Price Forecasting</marquee>'),
          "Coal Price Forecasting", tabName = "coal_forecasting",
                 icon = icon("line-chart", class = "fa-spin",lib="font-awesome"))
      )
    ),
    dashboardBody()
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. Thanks alot. Worked like a charm :) How can I change the color of same text?

Comment: You can change the background color like so:http://www.tagindex.net/html/text/marquee_example.html and the text like so:`<font color="red"><marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left"> Coal Price Forecasting</marquee>'` but it shifts the little arrow

Comment: Yeah. It shifts the arrow little bit down.